# Проблема с установкой плагина imagemin в gulp(require() of ES Module not supported)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, gulp, npm

Пытаюсь установить плагин imagemin. Пробовал устанавливать через import, но там возникает другая более сложная проблема. Как видите, я откатил версию imagemin до 7.1.0, но всё равно выдаёт ошибку. Ищу в гугле , пока не нашёл. type: "module" уже указан.
Вот код gulpfile.js

```
let project_folder = "dist";
let source_folder = "#src";
let sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));



let path = {
    build: {
        html: project_folder + "/",
        css: project_folder + "/css/",
        js: project_folder + "/js/",
        img: project_folder + "/img/",
        fonts: project_folder + "/fonts/",
    },
    src: {
        html: [source_folder + "/*.html", "!" + source_folder + "/_*.html"], // исключаем файлы, которые начинаются 
        // с подчёркивания для того чтобы в папку dist попадал только index.html
        css: source_folder + "/scss/style.scss",
        js: source_folder + "/js/script.js",
        img: source_folder + "/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}",
        fonts: source_folder + "/fonts/*.ttf ",
    },
    watch: {
        html: source_folder + "/**/*.html",
        css: source_folder + "/scss/**/*.scss",
        js: source_folder + "/js/**/*.js",
        img: source_folder + "/img/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}",
    },
    clean: "./" + project_folder + "/"
}

let { src, dest } = require(`gulp`),
    gulp = require(`gulp`),
    browsersync = require("browser-sync").create(),
    fileinclude = require("gulp-file-include"),
    del = require("del"),
    scss = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass')),
    autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer"),
    group_media = require("gulp-group-css-media-queries"),
    clean_css = require("gulp-clean-css"),
    rename = require("gulp-rename"),
    babel = require('gulp-babel'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');



function browserSync(params) {
    browsersync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./" + project_folder + "/"
        },
        port: 3000,
        notify: false
    })
}

function html(params) {
    return src(path.src.html)
        .pipe(fileinclude())
        .pipe(dest(path.build.html))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}


function css(params) {
    return src(path.src.css)
        .pipe(
            scss({ outputStyle: 'expanded' }).on('error', scss.logError)
        )
        .pipe(
            group_media()
        )
        .pipe(
            autoprefixer({
                overrideBrowserslist: ["last 5 version"],
                cascade: true
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(clean_css())
        .pipe(
            rename({
                extname: ".min.css"
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function js(params) {
    return src(path.src.js)
        .pipe(fileinclude())
        .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(
            uglify()
        )
        .pipe(
            rename({
                extname: ".min.js"
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function images(params) {
    return src(path.src.img)
        .pipe(
            imagemin({
                progressive: true,
                svgoPlugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
                interlaced: true,
                optimizationLevel: 3 // 0-7
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}


function watchFiles(params) {
    gulp.watch([path.watch.html], html); // live обновление страницы
    gulp.watch([path.watch.css], css);
    gulp.watch([path.watch.js], js);
    gulp.watch([path.watch.img], images);
}

function clean(params) {
    return del(path.clean); // удаляет все файлы , кроме index.html в папке dist
}

let build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(js, css, html, images));
let watch = gulp.parallel(build, watchFiles, browserSync);

exports.images = images;
exports.js = js;
exports.css = css;
exports.html = html;
exports.build = build;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = watch;
```

Json

```
{
    "name": "myproject",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Сборка gulp",
    "main": "Index.html",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "Fls",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "browser-sync": "^2.27.7",
        "del": "^6.0.0",
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": "^8.0.0",
        "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
        "gulp-clean-css": "^4.3.0",
        "gulp-file-include": "^2.3.0",
        "gulp-group-css-media-queries": "^1.2.2",
        "gulp-imagemin": "^7.1.0",
        "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-sass": "^5.0.0",
        "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
        "gulp-uglify-es": "^3.0.0",
        "sass": "latest",
        "type": "module"
    }
}
```

Вот фото из терминала [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В новых версиях Gulp и Imagemin Нужен синтаксис ES16, а не обычный CommonJS

Comment: Вот, в первом ответе все написано:
https://qna.habr.com/q/1048726